# how do i prevent redundant package and class names in python

Tags: python-3.x, import, constructor

I have a complex class hierarchy which involves harnessing a wide array of OS commands to provide a uniform API to them in an automation library.  Some of these commands are accessed via a cli interface, others via a rest based interface, and the classes therein have package names such as these:

```
cmd.interface.cli.mgmt
cmd.interface.cli.support
cmd.interface.rest

cmd.driver.cli.network_config
cmd.result.cli.network_config

cmd.driver.cli.stats
cmd.result.cli.stats

cmd.driver.rest.network_interface
cmd.result.rest.network_interface
```

etc, etc.

there are many of these, and they are all grouped logically and have a hierarchy of base classes, and they all contain a single class definition of basically the same name as the last file name in the package path.

i.e., an import statement and then "constructor" usage would look like this:

```
import cmd.driver.cli.network_config
.
.
.
config_driver = cmd.driver.cli.network_config.NetworkConfig(...)
```

I find the redundancy in this sort of class access to be really annoying, and it makes the code look kind of stupid.

Is there a good way to remove this naming redundancy while keeping the modules separate and intact?

Here are a few things I do **not** want to do to address this issue:

1.

```
from cmd.driver.cli.network_config import NetworkConfig as CliDriverNetworkConfig
from cmd.result.cli.network_config import NetworkConfig as CliResultNetworkConfig
from cmd.driver.rest.network_config import NetworkConfig as RestDriverNetworkConfig
```

(ugh!)

I don't want to pretend there is a cute name possible for each of these things.  I really want to **expose all the relevant information at time of use**:

```
config_driver = cmd.driver.cli.network_config.NetworkConfig(...)
```

(but I really want, and this should be enough to make the code understandable:

```
config_driver = cmd.driver.cli.NetworkConfig(...)
```

)

2. put 30 or so of such class defs in cmd/driver/cli/__ init __.py

(also yucky)

in perl, this would be done in this manner:

```
use Cmd::Driver::CLI::Network_Config;
.
.
.
my $config_driver = Cmd::Driver::CLI::Network_Config->new(...);
```

is there any mechanism in python that would allow me to more succinctly call the constructor on these classes without the package name redundancy and without hiding important details of which class out of several with similar but reliably distinct **full** names is being called?

................................................

ADDITIONAL COMMENT at post + 1 hour:

It occurs to me that perl is also doing the same sort of thing, where the package is Cmd::Driver::CLI::Network_Config and the class method being called therein is 'new'.  Thus the prettier look of the call in this case.

I guess if I name the module cmd.driver.cli.NetworkConfig and put a package scope method called 'new' which just calls cmd.driver.cli.NetworkConfig.NetworkConfig(...) I would get the same effect, such that I could then make the call:

```
import cmd.driver.cli.NetworkConfig
.
.
.
config_driver = cmd.driver.cli.NetworkConfig.new(...)
```

hmmmm...  i realize that this may not be "pythonic" in several senses, and I don't like mucking about behind the scenes too much (this sort of thing is always a risk), but maybe this is the way to get what i want if i'm dead-set on it...

................................................

ADDITIONAL COMMENT at post + 1 week:

Gosh no up-votes even?  Kind of a serious question.  Perhaps I should not have said how I'd do this in perl...  :-p  Ah, well.

Comment: ADDITIONAL COMMENT at post + 1 week:

Answer (score 0):

My proposition : uses __ import__ to define your function for instance.

```
def myInit(pathImport, *args):
  t  = __import__(pathImport+".network_config", globals(), locals(), [], 0)
  return t.NetworkConfig(*args)
```

and use is

```
config_driver = myInit('cmd.driver.cli', ...)
```

Comment: thanks, but it seems odd that I would need to do such a thing for an extremely standard pattern of a single class in a file and having an reasonable full class name for the constructor of that class.  I appreciate you taking the time to suggest though.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this in your top level module or `__init__.py`:

```
# import submodules, exposing them to things that import this module directly

from cmd.interface.cli import mgmt
from cmd.interface.cli import support
from cmd.interface import rest

from cmd.driver.cli import stats as driver_stats
from cmd.result.cli import stats as result_stats

# hide unneeded variables from things that import this module (optional)

__all__ = ['mgmt', 'support', 'rest', 'driver_stats', 'result_stats']
```

This will expose the simplified names as module member variables to anything that references your root module. You can even do variations of this pattern at multiple levels of your hierarchy.

Comment: i think that i do not want to make simplified names.  at the time of usage, every bit of the full name carries important information for the maintainer to easily see.  for example, in one section of code, i'll want x = cmd.driver.cli.x.X, and in an associated part right under that, i'll use x = cmd.driver.rest.x.X, and same for other result objects.  in this model, then, i suppose I could say  "from cmd.driver.cli.x import X as cmd_driver_cli_X" and then x = cmd_driver_cli_X(...).   hmmm...  better-  maybe as good as it gets I suppose...

Comment: @Bruce you don't have to do this in the top module. The example you provided regarding cmd.driver.cli.NetworkConfig can be achieved by importing NetworkConfig into the init file under cmd.driver.cli. Many python modules offer members under both submodules and the top level for convenient or descriptive access depending on the user's needs.

Comment: these comments are difficult to discuss much in.  what is the standard manner for me to respond with more serious details than work here?  should i edit my post?  or the answer post?  appreciate your help.